# Reference whole framework into Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, dll-reference

Currently, I'm building a C#-Console that allows me to enter any C# code into a CMD for instant execution. For this approach I'm using the Roslyn compiler, because it allows me to add more code into a session object on every command, so it's allowing me to i.e. initialize anything in the first command and use it in the second command.

In this console I want to be able to access the whole .NET framework, thus I added all references to my console project and tried to iterate those references to add those into the Roslyn session:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
AssemblyName[] references = assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().Where(x => !x.Name.StartsWith("Roslyn.")).ToArray();
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngine();
Session session = engine.CreateSession();
foreach (AssemblyName reference in references)
{
    session.AddReference(reference.FullName);
}
```

Unfortunately, I only get a few references my console actually use. I suspect the MSBuild compiler is very neat, detects that almost all of my references won't be used in my console, thus it won't include them at all. How I can get rid of that?

I really don't wish to parse the `.proj` file and maintain this list separately.

Comment: Yes, the compiler omits any references that are not actually used in the final assembly.  That's not specific to Roslyn, all C# compilers do this. Why would you want to "get rid of that"??  You can't.

Comment: You need to load the assemblies at run time. Since those assemblies are note necessarily needed by your host, you might as well maintain a list just for that and embed it as resource.

Comment: Or create an internal class with one field of, at least, one type from those assemblies.